# Make Label and Checkbox closer together in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have a `label` and a `checkbox` in my `view` that I would like next to each other.  However, as you can see in this picture I cannot get them any closer.[image]

Here is my view code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddTechNote", "Ticket", FormMethod.Post)) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TicketId)
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.Label("New Note", new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="text-align: right">
            @Html.Label("Public", new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.CheckBox("PublicNote", new { @class = "chk=style", @checked = "checked" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        @Html.TextArea("Note", new { cols = 600, @rows = 5 })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
        @*<div class="col-md-1 col-lg-offset-1">
        </div>
        *@
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Jesus,

This is what I get with the code you provided.  Thank you for your help so far.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried placing them within the same element?

Comment: @EBrown yes and they come out worse - on seperate lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following:
Use only one div for both `label` and `checkbox` like:

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="text-align: right">
    @Html.Label("Public", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.CheckBox("PublicNote", new { @class = "chk=style", @checked = "checked" })
</div>
```

The label need to wrap the input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Razor view, something like this:

```
<div class="@Model.ControlDimension">
    <div class="checkbox @Model.CheckBoxDivClasses">
        <label for="@Model.ControlName">@Html.Raw(Model.Label)@Model.ControlFor</label>        
        @Model.ValidationMessageFor
    </div>    
</div>
```

The control needs to be inside the label element.

In your case, I think ...:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="PublicNote">
            Public
            @Html.CheckBox("PublicNote", new { @class = "chk=style", @checked = "checked" })
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that looks like it will help but how do I get that to work if I am not using a model?

Comment: I added a example to my answer.

Comment: Jesus thank you but the checkbox is below to the right of the label.  I will add a pic to my original to show the result